# Changing text color with PHP session not working

Tags: php, html, css

My problem is only changing session variable from default text color to another text color.

here's my code that doesn't work below. how to correct it to work well?
thank you :)

```
<div class="welcome-admin">
                    <h3>Welcome: <?php echo "<span style="color:green;">.$_SESSION['Fname'].</span>";?></h3>
                </div>
```

the output is still the same as default color.

Comment: add `css` tag, drop `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Your encapsulation is incorrect. You have to many double quotes.

```
<h3>Welcome: <?php echo "<span style="color:green;">.$_SESSION['Fname'].</span>";?></h3>
```

Better off doing something like this

```
<h3>Welcome: <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $_SESSION['Fname'];?></span></h3>
```